# forward() not overridden in implementation of nn.Module in an example

Tags: module, pytorch, forward

In [this](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/link_pred.py) example, we see the following implementation of `nn.Module`:

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_channels, out_channels)

    def encode(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index).relu()
        return self.conv2(x, edge_index)

    def decode(self, z, edge_label_index):
        return (z[edge_label_index[0]] * z[edge_label_index[1]]).sum(dim=-1)

    def decode_all(self, z):
        prob_adj = z @ z.t()
        return (prob_adj > 0).nonzero(as_tuple=False).t()
```

However, in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#:%7E:text=Module-,forward(*input),-Defines%20the%20computation) we have that '`forward(*input)`' "Should be overridden by all subclasses."

Why is that not then the case in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `Net` module is meant to be used via two separate interfaces `encoder` and `decode`, at least it seems so... Since it doesn't have a `forward` implementation, then yes it is improperly inheriting from `nn.Module`. However, the code is still "valid", and will run properly but may have some side effects if you are using forward hooks.

The standard way of performing inference on a `nn.Module` is to *call* the object, *i.e.* calling the `__call__` function. This `__call__` function is implemented by the parent class *`nn.Module`* and will in turn do two things:

- handle forward hooks before or after the inference call
- call the `forward` function of the class.

The `__call__` function acts as a wrapper of `forward`.
So for this reason the `forward` function is expected to be overridden by the user-defined `nn.Module`. The only caveat of violating this design pattern is that it will effectively ignore any hooks applied on the `nn.Module`.